# how to get rid of undefined index

Tags: php

i am using this simple login for protecting a page.
When i choose a username which is not in the array, i get the message: undefined index on line 16.
How can i get rid of this message?

```
session_start();

$userinfo = array(
            'user1'=>'password1',
            'user2'=>'password2'
            );

if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
$_SESSION['username'] = '';
header('Location:  ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {

if($userinfo[$_POST['username']] == $_POST['password']) {

    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
}else {
     echo 'Login failed';
}
}

?>

<?php if($_SESSION['username']): ?>

        <p>You are logged in now and this is your secret area</p>
        <p><a href="?logout=1">Logout</a></p> <!-- logging out -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Define the index [ sorry :-) ]

Comment: What is the full error? What index is undefined?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: testusername in C:\wamp\www\test\protect2.php on line 17 It is just before the echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add an isset check into your conditional:

```
if(isset($userinfo[$_POST['username']]) && $userinfo[$_POST['username']] == $_POST['password']) {
```

Comment: What if, for some unknown and random reason, the password is `NULL`?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Then the conditional would fail - i dont see what you are getting at

Comment: "Then the conditional would fail" - That was my point. You cannot have a `NULL` password - just something to look out for.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ OK, i see. Yes that is a limitation

Answer (score 2):

Check the key exists.

```
if( array_key_exists($_POST['username'], $userinfo) ) {
  //User found
} else {
  //No user found
}
```

https://www.php.net/array_key_exists